# Get line number from file snippet

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, emf

I want to mark an EObject in a file with [IMarker](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIMarker.html). All I can use is a unique identifier which occurs as part of a line.

How do I get the number of the line that contains this identifier?

So i have this file which contains several bibtex entries like

```
@ARTICLE{Author2015,
    title={Hello World},
    ...
}
@BOOK{Author2000,
    title={Book Title},
    ...
}
```

And I have my object

```
BibtexObject bib = ...
String identifier = bib.getIdentifier(); // = "Author2000"
```

Do I have to check and count each line using `IFile#getContents()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify much about your relationship between the EObject (Java Object in memory) and the persisted file on the disk. Per default some XML serialization will persist your models while it looks like you use some other, textual, serialization. Maybe Xtext? Depending on the serialization, the line number might be very different. However, for just creating a Marker, you might not need the line number at all.

You can have a look in org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.action.ValidateAction on how Markers are created by EMF itself for validation results.

EMF usually stores its EObject URI for a Marker instead of line Numer, so you can get it from the Marker like

```
String uriAttribute = marker.getAttribute(EValidator.URI_ATTRIBUTE, null);
```

You can get the corresponding object from the ResourceSet

```
URI uri = URI.createURI(uriAttribute);    
resource.getResourceSet().getEObject(uri, true);
```

The other way round you can create a new Marker with the EValidator.URI_ATTRIBUTE set to the URI of the EObject in its containing Resource. You can get that by

```
resource.getURIFragment(myEObject)
```

I think the EMF URIs should be serialization independent and thus independent of concrete line numbers.